# How to align based on capitalized words?

Tags: regular-expressions, align

I have some SQL code in the following style:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test ( \n\
\  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, \n\
\  symbol TEXT NOT NULL, \n\
\  date TEXT NOT NULL, \n\
\  val DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL, \n\
\"
```

I'd like the datatypes to be aligned. In other words:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test ( \n\
\  id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, \n\
\  symbol TEXT NOT NULL, \n\
\  date   TEXT NOT NULL, \n\
\  val    DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL, \n\
\"
```

I thought using `align-regexp` with the pattern `[A-Z]+` would work, but it does not. Using `C-u M-x align-regexp` with `\(\s-*\)[A-Z]+` doesn't work either. Instead, it replaces the two spaces before the column names with a single space. I do not understand why this is.

So, my questions:

1. Why doesn't `align-regexp` with `[A-Z]+` work? Searching based on the same pattern correctly identifies the text.
2. What is the right regexp that would get this alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becase `align-regexp` is, by default, case-insensitive. Evaluate `(setq case-fold-search nil)` before `align-regexp`.